# using dma memory transfer from udp socket to RAM

Tags: linux, udp, dma

I have a bunch of data coming in to my server via UDP socket. These data need to be processed and get sent to our clients. Because the incoming data is large, I am thinking maybe I should optimize this process using DMA transfer - I want the network data to be stored directly to RAM so that user space applications can access them quickly.

I have limited experience with device drivers and I don't know much about network sockets. My questions are :

1. Can DMA transfer be used in this scenario
2. Would it actually reduce the overhead and improve the performance?

Comment: Do you want the network interface to put UDP packet payload in a program's allocated buffers with the less kernel/driver intervention ? Something like zero-copy UDP ?

Comment: Zero copy UDP is exactly what I was thinking about. I’m not familiar with the network interface, but is it safe to say that network interface has a certain buffer, and when that buffer gets filled up, an interrupt gets triggered, copying buffer data to kernel space which gets copied again to user space memory?

Comment: Without zerocopy, with most network interface, the kernel allocate buffers, gives them to the drivers that setup the network interface so that, upon packet reception, use DMA to write to those buffers. Then, when user program read the socket, kernel copies theses buffers into userspace provided buffers.

Comment: @YannDroneaud I see, so the network interface uses dma to write directly to kernel buffers, and then that gets copied to the user side. Do you by any chance know how much overhead I will be reducing if I use zerocopy? I'm not sure if zerocopy really saves that much time

Comment: @YannDroneaud Do you also know any tutorials on how to do this? I have linux device drivers book which is very helpful, but was wondering if there were other resources that I can use

Comment: Zerocopy, for example used with RDMA network stack, can save some memory bandwidth by reducing the memory copies. RDMA aware interface can achieve better latencies, lower CPU consumption. But I can tell you if this can save much time. You will have to look at your current hot spots (using perf for example).

Comment: some episode articles from the linux journal regarding high-performance network programming and also zero-copy may be able to help you - https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/9815 ; https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6345

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays most network adapters use DMA to deliver packets to host memory on receive and grab packet data from it when transmitting. But in regular kernel drivers, the DMA memory buffers aren't accessible from applications. The data is copied between kernel-side and user-side buffers.

If the requirement in question, "user space applications can access them quickly", implies avoding such data copies between kernel-side and user-side buffers, then one should consider using so-called *kernel-bypass* techniques, for example, [`PACKET_MMAP`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/networking/packet_mmap.html) API of Linux kernel or [`DPDK`](https://www.dpdk.org/).

In a nutshell, `PACKET_MMAP` allows an application to set up a memory buffer shared between the kernel- and userspace and access packet data directly. This is what the workflows look like:

```
[setup]     socket() -------> creation of the capture socket
            setsockopt() ---> allocation of the circular buffer (ring)
                              option: PACKET_RX_RING
            mmap() ---------> mapping of the allocated buffer to the
                              user process

[capture]   poll() ---------> to wait for incoming packets

[shutdown]  close() --------> destruction of the capture socket and
                              deallocation of all associated
                              resources.
```

```
[setup]         socket() -------> creation of the transmission socket
                setsockopt() ---> allocation of the circular buffer (ring)
                                  option: PACKET_TX_RING
                bind() ---------> bind transmission socket with a network interface
                mmap() ---------> mapping of the allocated buffer to the
                                  user process

[transmission]  poll() ---------> wait for free packets (optional)
                send() ---------> send all packets that are set as ready in
                                  the ring
                                  The flag MSG_DONTWAIT can be used to return
                                  before end of transfer.

[shutdown]      close() --------> destruction of the transmission socket and
                                  deallocation of all associated resources.
```

Packets are handled in batches (blocks), which avoids costly kernel-to-userspace context switches.

One can learn more about `PACKET_MMAP` from the documentation (link above). Furthermore, this mechanism is already exercised by `libpcap`-based tools (`tcpdump`, `wireshark` and the likes).

Comment: Note that, with `PACKET_MMAP`, the only copy that's eliminated is a copy from a kernel buffer to userland.  Data *is* copied from a kernel socket buffer (skbuff) to the memory-mapped buffer, so it's not a direct "adapter DMAs data into memory that's accessible to userland" mechanism.

Comment: So in this process there is actually a data copy and not just a _cloning_ of the associated sk_buff